# comboBox stopped displaying SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

My code which was working before, pull tables from a database is suddenly not displaying in my comboBox. It can be seen by the comboBox that data is being pulled but the items are not visible. As shown below:

[image]

This is my code to pull the tables:

```
private void fillOutputFile()
    {

        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=bid;Initial Catalog=BI;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                string query = "Select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                    comboBox5.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
                    //   con2.Close();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Windows Credentials does not have the rights to access/write to this table./nPlease contact your DB Administrator");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Debug the code and see query returns records or not

Comment: Verify that you are accessing correct data base. apart from this your code seems to be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this might seem weird but it might actually work. Make a copy of your project to another location on your PC. After doing that, delete the old project. Copy the new project to where your deleted project was before.Open up up VS and try debugging the project that you copied once more. It may work

Comment: I can't believe this actually works. Any idea why this solved it?

Comment: @AdamNewman I am thinking maybe the directory got corrupted in some way? I am not sure, I was only messing around in the past and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Check the `DrawMode` property of your ComboBox and make sure it is NOT set to `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable`. You need it set to `Normal`.

Having it set to `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable` leads to this:

[image]